# Appfabric Error: ErrorCode<ERRCMC0003>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Error in client configuration file

Tags: .net, gac, appfabric, azure-appfabric

I am getting this error when trying to use caching for app fabric. 
I was following the example given in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983488.aspx) article.

ErrorCode:SubStatus:Error in client configuration file.

"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for dataCacheClient: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core' 
or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified. 
(C:\Projects\TestResults\test 2012-04-30 14_51_12\Out\Tests.DLL.config line 5)"
here is the text from line 5: "                
 
       
               
                   
               
       "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this error was caused by the referencing of two different versions of the Windows Azure SDK. I ended up using the nuget reference to [ServerAppFabric.Client](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServerAppFabric.Client) from all my projects and this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know whether you’re using the latest Windows Azure SDK (which includes AppFabric). You can get it from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/. Moreover, the article you’re referencing is a bit old. There’re some break changes in later CTPs of caching service. For an up to date version of caching tutorial, I would like to suggest you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_buildingappswithcacheservice_topic3#_Toc310505080.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.